# 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'isatty'

Tags: python, kivy

Soy principiante en Kivy. Estoy creando una aplicación con Pafy para descargar audio y video de Youtube y obtengo el siguiente error. Estoy usando Python 2.7 y Kivy 1.9.1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex.py", line 46, in <module>
 MyApp().run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
 runTouchApp()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
 EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
 self._mainloop()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 290, in _mainloop
 EventLoop.idle()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in idle
 self.dispatch_input()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
 post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 281, in post_dispatch_input
 wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-XUuuyR/Kivy/kivy/_event.c:7699)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 138, in on_touch_up
 self.dispatch('on_release')
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-XUuuyR/Kivy/kivy/_event.c:7654)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-XUuuyR/Kivy/kivy/_event.c:13497)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1108, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-XUuuyR/Kivy/kivy/_event.c:12329)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1557, in custom_callback
 exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
File "./kv/main.kv", line 7, in <module>
 on_release: root.Download_Audio()
File "ex.py", line 30, in Download_Audio
 audio = pafy.new(link) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pafy/pafy.py", line 124, in new
 return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 29, in __init__
 super(YtdlPafy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pafy/backend_shared.py", line 96, in __init__
 self._fetch_basic()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pafy/backend_youtube_dl.py", line 38, in _fetch_basic
 self._ydl_info = ydl.extract_info(self.videoid, download=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 785, in extract_info
 ie_result = ie.extract(url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 440, in extract
 ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1537, in _real_extract
 ytplayer_config = self._get_ytplayer_config(video_id, video_webpage)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1248, in _get_ytplayer_config
 patterns, webpage, 'ytplayer.config', default=None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 782, in _search_regex
 if not self._downloader.params.get('no_color') and compat_os_name != 'nt' and sys.stderr.isatty():
AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

Aquí está mi código:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

import pafy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from os import listdir

kv_path = './kv/'
for kv in listdir(kv_path):
    Builder.load_file(kv_path + kv)

class AudioButton(Button):
    pass

class VideoButton(Button):
    pass

class Container(GridLayout):
    display = ObjectProperty()

    def Download_Audio(self):
        link = self.display.text
        audio = pafy.new(link)  
        archivo = audio.getbestaudio()
        archivo.download()

    def Download_Video(self):
        link = self.display.text
        video = pafy.new(link)
        archivo1 = video.getbest()
        archivo1.download()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Downloader"
        return Container()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Y los archivos .kv:

```
<Container>:
display: display
rows: 1
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    AudioButton:
        on_press: root.Download_Audio()
    VideoButton:
        on_press: root.Download_Video()
TextInput:
    id: display
    font_size: 20
    text: 'Link here'

<AudioButton>:
text: "Download Audio"
font_size: 50

<VideoButton>
text: "Download Video"
font_size: 50
```

Comment: hello, please translate your question, you are on stackoverflow in spanish

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.